# using a VHDL generate statement in a function

Tags: case, vhdl

I want to use generate  statement but in my code I have a case statements which only takes sequential statements.

Then I thought I will use it in a package where I can define a function such that there also I am getting error as : **'Illegal Sequential statement'.**

So what can be done. Any suggestions?

Code block:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE work.my_package.all;

-- Entity for ALU component
-- Use this Entity for your C&A project

ENTITY ALU_E IS
  PORT(
    reset_n     : in std_logic;
    clk         : in std_logic;
    OperandA    : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    OperandB    : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    Operation   : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    Start       : in std_logic;
    Result_Low  : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    Result_High : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    Ready   : out std_logic;
    Errorsig    : out std_Logic);
END ALU_E;

architecture Behavioral_ALU of ALU_E is 
signal c : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal carry_internal :std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

COMPONENT fulladder IS
  PORT(
    a: IN std_logic;
    b: IN std_logic;
    cin : IN std_logic;
    cout: OUT std_logic;
    s: OUT std_logic );
END component fulladder;

begin

adders: for N in 0 to 3 generate
            ff1:fulladder
            port map
            (a => OperandA(N),b => OperandB(N),cin => carry_internal(N),cout => carry_internal(N+1),s => c(N));
            end generate adders;            
            c(4) <= carry_internal(4);


process(clk,reset_n)
begin

if reset_n = '0' then
    if (clk'event) then
        case Operation is 
            when "000" =>   --no operation
            NULL;

            when "001" =>   --Rotate left logical operator ?0000?&A by B steps
            c <= rotlef (OperandA,OperandB);

            when "010" =>   --Rotate right logical operator ?0000?&A by B steps (result width is 8 bit)
            c <= rotrig (OperandA,OperandB);

            when "011" =>   --Bitwise XOR operation
            Result_Low <= OperandA xor OperandB;

            when "100" =>   --Sum of A and B
            --here i want to use a statement such that i can call the gatelevel      --add function
--I have already all functions gatelevel defined when i try to use portmap or ----generate it gives an error illegal sequential statement 
            when Others =>
            NULL;
        end case;
    end if;
end if;
end process;
end Behavioral_ALU;
```

Comment: Format your question into a readable form.

Comment: That code look OK to me (at a cursory inspection), can you explain in more detail what your problem is?

Comment: You need to post more code. You have ports in your `fulladder` connected to things that we can't see any declaration for, for example `OperandA`. There is nothing fundamentally wrong with instantiating a component inside a generate loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of misconceptions in the question.

First the title : there is no function in your actual code. What you have done with the `for ... generate` statement is generate a separate piece of hardware, operating in parallel with the main process. It will always operate, and always drive signal 'c' with the sum, as if you had written `c <= a + b;` in place of the `for ... generate`. It's always, continuously working, not a function you can call only when you want to.

Second, that means that both the adder and the clocked process drive `c` all the time, with different values. This will not go well... in fact you should see "XXXX" on signal `c` in simulation.

What I think you want to do is create a new signal, called `sum` for the adder's output, and drive `sum`, not `c`, in the `for ... generate`. Then, in the Case statement, assigning `sum` to `c` will accomplish the Add operation.

Comment: Thanks I already made changes in my code but i don't want it to work parallel to my process instead i want to build a function maybe which i can call at the case statement as i have done it previously shift right or left operations.

Comment: Look at the synthesis results in detail. Just use c <=( others=> '0') to remove operations that aren't working yet. Or remove them all and re-add them one by one. You'll find that the hardware required for those operations (rotlef etc)  IS ALWAYS THERE and always working in parallel; it's just ignored when you're not looking at it. You get no choice about this, you can't make gates appear and disappear at the flick of a switch, or an opcode... So this adder won't be any different.

Comment: PS: There is also likely to be a warning during synthesis about a signal with multiple drivers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as why you get the error messages you do, a component instantiation statement or generate statement is a concurrent statement, while a case choice or a function body is comprised of sequential statements.

You don't need a function, you need the sum and carry out from the generate statement instantiated four `fulladder`s.
o
Dummy up an entity/architecture pair for fulladder:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity fulladder is
    port (
        a:    in  std_logic;
        b:    in  std_logic;
        cin:  in  std_logic;
        cout: out std_logic;
        s:    out std_logic 
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of fulladder is

begin
    s <= a xor b xor cin;
    cout <= (a and b) or (a and cin) or (b and cin);
end architecture;
```

Dummy up a non functional `my_package`:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
package my_package is
    function rotlef (a, b: std_logic_vector)  return std_logic_vector;
    function rotrig (a, b: std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector;
end package;
package body my_package is
    function rotlef (a, b: std_logic_vector)  return std_logic_vector is
        variable ret_val: std_logic_vector (a'range);
    begin
        return ret_val;
    end function;
    function rotrig (a, b: std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
        variable ret_val: std_logic_vector (a'range);
    begin
        return ret_val;
    end function;
end package body;
```

*(note the function return value lengths match the left operand length)*

Add a new declaration for the output of the generated `fulladder`s:

```
architecture changed of alu_e is 
    signal c:               std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal carry_internal:  std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

    signal s:               std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- added
```

Change the generate statement to use the new signal for the sum:

```
adders: 
    for n in 0 to 3 generate
ff1:
        fulladder
            port map (
                a => operanda(n),
                b => operandb(n),
                cin => carry_internal(n),
                cout => carry_internal(n+1),
                s => s(n)  -- was c(n)
            );
    end generate;            

    -- c(4) <= carry_internal(4);
```

*(eliminating the assignment to c(4))*

And change the sequence of statements for choice "100":

```
                    when "100" =>   --sum of a and b
                        result_low <= s; -- added
                        result_high(0) <= carry_internal(4); --(un)signed?
```

And your design analyzes, elaborates and simulates (while not doing much - no assignments in the process for case `others` when `operation` is undriven and all `U`s, I didn't write a testbench to drive `operation` or provide it with a default value).

Notice the declaration of `c` has a length of 8 while the return value of the two functions will match their `a` input (length 4).

If you were to execute the dummy functions for `operation`s `"001"` or `"010"` you'd get a simulation error due to length mismatch on the right hand side. I left this as is with no insight in to whether or not your `rotlef` or `rotrig` functions actually return a longer length.

In general you only want an 8 bit result for multiplies.  The length of `c` and how it get's assigned to `result_low` and `result_high` aren't apparent (as yet).

It wasn't possible to discern whether you're doing signed or unsigned arithmetic without more detail. Instead of:

```
                        result_high(0) <= carry_internal(4); --(un)signed?
```

A signed sign extension could look like:

```
                        result_high <= (others => carry_internal(4)); --sign extended
```

Note that when you instantiate your multiplier you'd also want to use a new signal declaration for the 8 bit result. Modifying your rotate operations to assign `result_low` and `result_high` would allow `c` to be used for an instantiated multiply, although you might choose to rename it.

Think of the case statement in the process statement as instantiating a multiplexer, and in some cases you happen to be also expressing logic on inputs. The `xor` or the sign extension or function calls (which are expressions) are examples.

When you have instantiated components providing function you want to connect their output to a multiplexer input.